# Apple terminal no home and end key - Use cmd left or cmd right

Tags: keyboard, terminal, keybindings

How do I make

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> move the text cursor very left and right of the terminal entry line. This keyboard shortcut works on most things on my mac book but not the Terminal.

Usually I use the home and end keys on other non apple computers. Strangely enough <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> achieve this in the mac terminal but it is the wrong key combination in my opinion. I want to do it using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.

It is similar to this question, however I want to specifically map it to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.

[Can home and end keys be mapped when using Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12997/can-home-and-end-keys-be-mapped-when-using-terminal?rq=1)

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a purist: ⌃+E and ⌃+A are the right ones, and ⌘+← and ⌘+→ are wrong. The E and A also work everywhere else in standard Mac text editing places, and on every Linux, Unix and BSD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Better Touch Tool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net) for this (it's no longer free, 5$ minimum), just assign keyboard shortcuts  to work in **Terminal** app only. Remap <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Here's the sample:

[image]

Comment: BTT is no longer free, but has a "pay what you want" license, with a minimum of $5

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga thanks for the update! Next time feel free to edit an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust the keybindings in Terminals preferences under Profiles -> Keyboard. This is on a Profile by profile basis. Map <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>OH</kbd> (`\033OH`) to the Home key to goto the beginning of a line and <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>OF</kbd> (`\033OF`) to the End key to go to the end of a line.

[image: Terminal Preference]